# Temporal logic (e.g., LTL) repository

Tags: logic, translation, temporal, nlp

I am currently dealing with the problem of formalizing the content of natural language texts by means of temporal logic, for instance LTL.

An example would be the phrase

> "When a train is approaching, a train will eventually cross",

that should correspond to an LTL specification like

> G(train_approaching ---> F(train_crossing))

I would like to consider the problem as a translation task, from natural language to LTL. In order to train a translation model, among other things, I'd need a proper training set, in which each instance should be represented by the natural language text, paired with the corresponding LTL (or another kind of temporal logic) formula.

I have already found these resources:

- http://patterns.projects.cs.ksu.edu/documentation/patterns/ltl.shtml A repository of property patterns (based on LTL), for a total of around 100 instances
- https://gitlab.lrz.de/i7/ltlstore LTL Store, which is a repository of LTL formulas, however without a paired natural language text (it could still be useful as "monolingual" training data)

Of course, the overall goal would be that of handling full-logic, however I may also focus on a subset of temporal logic-based patterns to begin with.

Do you know any other dataset that I could use as training data for this purpose?